# SQLite Android Logcat error for select statement

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

02-23 20:16:17.499: E/AndroidRuntime(25817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.makkosarka/com.example.makkosarka.Table.Table}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.makkosarka/
com.example.makkosarka.Table.Liga1}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

and here are the methods that are trying to select records from this table and than display 
in listview

```
    private void populateListFromDB(){
        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows("1");
        startManagingCursor(cursor);


        String[] columnFromTable = new String[]
    {DBadapter.KEY_HOSTID, DBadapter.GUESTID, DBadapter.KEY_HSCORE , DBadapter.KEY_GSCORE };


 int[] toLayoutFild = new int[] {R.id.txtview_name, R.id.txtview_gameno, R.id.txtview_won, R.id.txtview_lost, };

SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout,
cursor, columnFromTable, toLayoutFild);

ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_table);
mylistview.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

This is in the Adapter class and i'm not even selecting the "_id"(KEY_ROWID) column

```
  public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = new String[] {KEY_HOSTID, KEY_GUESTID,
 KEY_HSCORE, KEY_GSCORE};
    public Cursor getAllRows(String league) {
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DUELS_TABLE, ALL_COLUMNS, 
                        null, null, null, null, null, null);
      if (c != null) {
     c.moveToFirst();
        }
      return c;
     }
```

What does that error mean is it possible that the table is not created at all?
I have two tables and I`m using the same method to select records for the other one it works perfectly but for this it shows this error listed on the top of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is in the Adapter class and i'm not even selecting the "_id"(KEY_ROWID) column

`CursorAdapter` and its subclasses *require* that the `Cursor` have a column named `_id`. Use your own if you have one, or else switch to `rawQuery()` so you can include `ROWID AS _id` in your list of columns to return.